# How to pass the proper object to mapper.readValue()

Tags: java, jackson

I'm trying to map a json api response to an object and IntelliJ is complaining.  It's saying `cannot resolve method readValue(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object[]);`.  I realize I'm not passing the correct parameter but I've tried `responseClass.class` and `responseClass.getClass()` with no luck.

Usage:

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.setResponseClass(User.class);
```

Definition:

```
MyClass {
    private Object responseClass;

    public void setResponseClass(Object responseClass) {
        this.responseClass = responseClass;
    }

    public Object getResponseClass() {
        return responseClass;
    }

    public void getApiResponse() {
        //some code here

        ObjectMapper mapper = new com.MyApp.Utility.ObjectMapper();

        //some code here

        //I've tried responseClass.class and responseClass.getClass(), it didn't like either of them
        mapper.readValue(response, responseClass);

        //more code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Why isn't **responseClass** declared as **private Object responseClass**? Doing responseClass.class or responseClass.getClass() will not work as you are getting the Class Object of a Class Object when you want the Class Object of an Instance Object.

Comment: What is `com.MyApp.Utility.ObjectMapper`? Did you wrap the Jackson ObjectMapper? Also, you've obliterated your type to be mapped, by storing it as an `Object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a really odd way of mapping JSON responses to object, using Jackson. I assume you just want to be able to map arbitrary classes using a utility class? Here's an example of a much easier way to accomplish this. Note that this uses the `ObjectMapper` class that comes with your Jackson distro:

```
public class JSONUtil {
    private ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JSONUtil() {
        super();
        // Set ObjectMapper configuration and properties here
    }

    public <T> T deserialize(final String response, final Class<T> responseClass) {
        if(response == null || responseClass == null) return null;

        return mapper.readValue(response, responseClass);
    }
}
```

Now, you *could* still map your responses from JSON using the class you posted, with some modifications:

```
public class MyClass<T> {
    private Class<T> responseClass;

    public MyClass(final Class<T> responseClass) {
        super();
        this.responseClass = responseClass;
    }

    public void getApiResponse(final String response) {

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final T values = mapper.readValue(response, responseClass);

        //more code here
    }
}
```

And using it as such:

```
MyClass<User> myClass = new MyClass<User>(User.class);
myClass.getApiResponse(someJsonString);
```

Comment: Perception... if this is an odd implementation of Jackson, can you point me to a more standardized way of doing it?  I'd like to learn what's considered good practice.  Thanks for the detailed response and effort ... +1

Comment: @Webnet - maybe I should not have said 'odd', but I've honestly never seen anyone wrap `ObjectMapper`, which is itself largely a facade object with a significant number of methods. Is there a particular reason you are doing that?

Comment: I'm doing it based off of what a guy at my work did.  The wrapper only exists to overwrite the constructor with configuration settings.  I need to do some research into the default settings and see if it's necessary, but I haven't done that yet.

Comment: How would you implement the JSONUtil class as you have above?  I'm sort of new to `T` implementation.

Comment: The utility class as shown, works. Now, in order to provide additional settings to the ObjectMapper you just need to specify them in the constructor. See edits to answer.

Comment: Which class would extend the JSONUtil?

Comment: @Webnet - None, you use the JSONUtil as this - `JSONUtil util = new JSONUtil(); final User user = util.readValue(json, User.class);`.